# iPhone - Main.storyboard .xib file with version control Git issue

Tags: ios, xcode, git, storyboard, xib

we are working as a team on a swift project, sometimes when we synchronize the code we get errors in xib files.

I got this error in Main.storyboard file:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6254" systemVersion="14C1510" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="RRo-EU-Hod">
=======
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6254" systemVersion="13F34" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="foF-cS-VsG">
>>>>>>> 78f219050811a64628c3c1c28fe8cea45ebec3a1
```

i tried to remove one of them, it didn't work.

I see there is differences in the `initialViewController` here.
but i am not able to get the `Interface Builder` to fix it.

when  i click on `interface builder` i get this errror:

[image]

so what can be a suggested solution for this ?

---

Comment: Mmmm... I Strongly suggest you to reset to a working version and then just agree on who can change those files. ;)

Comment: well, I would like to solve it this way, but already we both did a massive changes, resetting can be last solution @Napolux

Comment: In the future you may want to break things up into different storyboards to avoid conflicts.  You can also lock views in IB to prevent other people from changing them.  You'll have to just look very closely at all the changes and try to fix the ids.  I've been here.  You'll find it goes much quicker the second and third time you rebuild something in IB.

Comment: so for now the only solution can be to reset to the previous version, then agree on who can do changes in the IB? @i_am_jorf

Comment: No, you can try to resolve the merge conflicts by hand by looking at the logs.  Or you can give up, revert, and re-do the changes serially.  There is no magic bullet, though, that I know of.

Comment: @i_am_jorf thank you i am still trying to rebase the merges to previous versions to know where is this problem happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the line that came from the other team member, and keep the line created on my computer. then I always unstage that line, as well the other team member unstaged it.